# how to change Tableau Filter Content Size?

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I know how to change the font size of the drop-downs, however, it did not change on the dashboard once i selected on item. For example, how to make the filter box/"(All)" bigger? Thanks! [image]

Comment: No you can't. It is not something possible

Answer (score 1):

We have this functionality in latest version of Tableau, please check the version you use. Click on the top corner of filter and choose the Format filter and set control. A pane appears on the left side change the Body font to increase the filter values bigger as required.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **short answer** is that you can change the filter box size (unfortunatelly).

The **long answer** is that you can try to make a simple workaround using Text/buttons in your dashboard and for each of those define a filter action ([see the Tableau guide about it](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.htm)).
Of course, it depends how many state your filter will have...if they are too many this will be a long work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the filter on the dashboard will not change size. It might not be worth the effort for a workaround.